# No route matches "/sessions.json

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, routes, objectiveresource

So why would I be getting this error and why its pointing to localhost instead of localhost:3000?

***Completed in 27ms (View: 3, DB: 13) | 406 Not Acceptable [http://localhost/sessions.json]***

I am trying to use ObjectiveResource (iphone app) and Rails.  ObjectiveResource points to sessions.json with a Post I guess when creating a session.

In my routes file I am using

`map.resources :sessions 
map.connect ':controller.:format'

map.connect ':controller/:action.:format'`

Comment: Found the issue before_filter :not_logged_in_required, :only => [:new, :create] . If I remove this it works.  Is there another way to achieve before_filter :not_logged_in_required, :only => [:new, :create] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your routes.rb you only need this:

```
map.resources :sessions
```

Your path is correct but you need `responds_to` block in the action

```
def create
    Session.create(params[:session])
    responds_to do |format|
        format.json 
    end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to register json as a Mime Type. Check that in the file `app_root/config/initializers/mime_types.rb` you have a line like:

```
Mime::Type.register_alias "application/json", :json
```